# deviceMotion rotationRate is null on iOS 13.4

Tags: javascript, ios, gyroscope

I use devicemotion event to access gyroscope on Safari since iOS 11.

History :

- On iOS 11 / 12, gyroscope access is open and just need to listen devicemotion event.
- Starting on iOS 12.2, Apple has blocked gyroscope access and you need to activate an option on safari settings
- Since iOS 13, Apple has implemented the "DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission" to ask gyroscope access and when user agree, devicemotion event has the key "rotationRate" with alpha / beta / gamma values (before agreed, value is null).

Problem :

On iOS 13.4 with no code change on my side and on all my projects using this feature, rotationRate is always null  even if user agree gyroscope access.

I searched for an official answer from Apple but nothing available.
It looks like a bug but maybe implementation on my side is wrong ?

Good to know on my code :

First, I listen devicemotion event (with rotationRate null), when interface is ready, user clicks on a button, gyroscope access asked and rotationRate has values.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug in iOS 13.4 because even the [webxr polyfill](https://github.com/immersive-web/webxr-polyfill/blob/master/build/webxr-polyfill.js) fails to detect which capabilities has the device because they have (line 3770):

```
if (this.isWithoutDeviceMotion) {
  window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', this.onDeviceOrientationCallback_);
} else {
  window.addEventListener('devicemotion', this.onDeviceMotionCallback_);
}
```

The condition evaluates to false, so devicemotion is used and then `rotationRate` and `accelerationIncludingGravity` are both null.

So I think the workaround from now is listen to deviceorientation event instead devicemotion, even having been requested permissions in advance, which is mandatory anyway.

Comment: Thank you for you answer and you are totally right ! I use the same library and i edited isWithoutDeviceMotion to work for iOS 13.4 and superior (use deviceorientation for now).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same here, rotation data is null.
But acceleration and accelerationIncludingGravity are not null, you can use these instead.